# How to format input text for 10 square box with digits

Tags: html, css, input, textfield, masking

I need an input text box that hold max of 10 digits (if less then 10 right aligned) Input should have 20px height and 200px width.
Input should consist from 10 boxes (10px10px) and when user enter digits it have to display single digit per box.
I managed to simulate those boxes with background

```
background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, black, black 1px, 
transparent 1px, transparent 20px);
background-position: 100%;
```

Using monospace font-family helped but still cant make it look and work as needed.
Is this possible to achieve and can you provide me some small working snippet for that?

Answer (score 0):

Are you making something like a serial number input? Do you specifically want to use one input field or would you consider using multiple input elements? If you want to use multiple inputs, here's a good [StackOverflow question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25272036/auto-advance-input-fields-multi-part-serial-number) describing how to auto-advance from one input to another.

Or are you looking for something else? Could you maybe provide more details and the markup you are applying that CSS to?

Comment: I created a fiddle for this. https://jsfiddle.net/gbh7myhj/
One input field that looks like 10 box and when I entered digits every digit should be in one of those "square boxes"

Comment: "Only" problem is letter spacing for last digit. If letter spacing after last digit does not exist everything will be easy with letter-spacing and some right padding. But...